# How do I "correctly configure" the Stackdriver Debugger for my Node.js App Engine service in Google Cloud platform?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-appengine-node

So I've deployed a simple Node.js app on Google App Engine Standard Environment and when I navigate to the Debug section of my serivce/app I get this message:

***"Stackdriver Debugger is not correctly configured for your project."***

When I click on the "Fix" button it then says

***"Please fix the following issue and try again"***

I press the fix button and  it says:

***"Stackdriver Debugger has been correctly configured for your project."***

Then it says

***"Stackdriver Debugger has been correctly configured for your project."***

***"The Stackdriver Debugger is now correctly configured, however it might take up to 30 minutes for the changes to be applied."***

When I hit continue, it goes back to the original message and says:
***"Stackdriver Debugger is not correctly configured for your project."***

It's an infinite loop and no amount of waiting seems to be able show any difference

I've enabled the API in my project as it says to in the docs,
I have this at the top of my main node script:

```
require('@google-cloud/debug-agent').start({ allowExpressions:true});
```

Nothing seems to make a difference. Anyone able to shed some light on this?

Comment: I tried this in a clean project, with a simple "Hello World" app, npm installing the debug-agent and then the require and it works for me. I did not include `{ allowExpressions: true}`. If you have Google Cloud Support, you may want to ping a case and ask one of the engineers to check your project. Otherwise, perhaps create a new project and app from scratch. If that works, compare the two deployments for differences.

Comment: It may (!?) be worth reviewing the API's metrics too: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/clouddebugger.googleapis.com/metrics?project=${PROJECT}

Comment: I have had this problem. My solution was to redeploy the app (gcloud app deploy). I do not know why this corrected the issue. In my case it was an AE Standard Python 2.7 app. Also, verify that your app is actually running and serving traffic correctly. The debugger cannot run in a crashed app.

Comment: @DazWilkin I'm going to try this!
What would that link show me? I don't have permissions to view that?

Comment: @JohnHanley Interesting point! This may contain the answer, let me try something

Comment: You'll need to replace `{PROJECT}` with your Project ID to view the page. It will show you what API calls are being made against the Debugger and which, if any are succeeding.

Comment: @JohnHanley what you said worked, I had to have live routes in my app and make sure it didn't die